# xiaomi redmi 3s phone not displaying visual studio 2017 Debug Target dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I create cross platform xamarin app using visual studio 2017.
try to connect xiaomi redmi 3s prime phone for debugging purpose.
but its not displaying vs 2017 Debug target drop down.

**Steps I followed:**

1. setting --> About phone --> MIUI version[8.1] (tapped 7 times) ("you are already a developer" message comes)
2. setting --> Additional settings --> Developer options --> Enabled USB debugging.

[visual studio screen short where i am facing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ7zm.png)

I tried so many ways but no use, 
Help to resolve this issue.

Comment: When you connect the phone does it prompt you to allow debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved by the below steps:

To solve problem with ADB Interface driver, I've installed Mi PC Suite - MiSetup3.2.1.3111_2717, and it helps! mobile Phone successfully connected to visual studio and I installed my test app

Thanks